# Watch Document in TextMate 2 "Not Watching"

Tags: textmate

I have been a longtime TM1 user, but the recent updates to 10.9 and subsequently 10.10 have left Ruby broken.  For example, cmd+{ no longer completes to an environment, although cmd+i does wrap in \emph oddly enough. I did try to patch this per the email sent by the developers over the summer, but it remains broken and I have given up on TM 1.

To get more on the TM track, I have decided to move to using TM2.  All of the key bindings work in TM2, but now I cannot get TextMate LaTeX Watch Document to "Watch."  When hitting cntl+cmd+w (or using the menu option) to watch the document, it compiles the document and pulls up the pdf in Skim.  Any subsequent edits will not update in the pdf document.

FWIW, in the LaTeX Preferences pop-up in TM2, I have "Use Latexmk" checked as well as "Show pdf automatically."  Furthermore, Watch Document *does* work in TM1 for me.

To summarize:  What must one do in TM2 (and OSX Yosemite, if that is an issue) to get the Watch Document feature to automatically update the compiled pdf document as it did in TM1?

Edit:  To make matters worse, compiling via cmd+r quickly opens the document in Skim, but then Skim immediately crashes.

Comment: Have you configured Skim correctly about automatic refreshing of a document?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes.  I have pdftex-sync support enabled for textmate.  In particular, I do _not_ have checked "Check for file changes" since it is my understanding that a perl script automatically updates between textmate and skim.

Comment: Okey. I'm no expert, so I don't know. I'm glad CMD+\{ doesn't work for you, it stopped working here some time ago (Mountain Lion), I'm not alone. I think this question might get more answers if you ask on GitHub on the LaTeX bundle, or even in another StackExchange site (like StackOverflow or SuperUser). Good luck.

Comment: Thank-you, Manuel.  I will probably head over to github.  If something good comes of it, I will repost here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I was able to use TM2 to write an article for TUGBoat, and I'm fairly sure it was compiling okay under Yosemite with cmd-R, with Skim as viewer. I use latexmk in TextMate, but not the "Watch Document" feature. Crashes under Yosemite in PDF Kit (used by Skim) are expected, since it's unfortunately really buggy.

Comment: Update: I just tried TextMate (version 2.0-alpha.9561) under Yosemite, and I can compile a document and sync both directions with Skim. "Watch document" appears to work just fine, also, and updates the PDF after I save in TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: to have Bundle Development on in your TextMate 2 Preferences. It points to Ruby 1.8. I'm no expert on the matter, however. I can only report I had initial problems with Ruby when I switched to Yosemite Beta (I'm now on Beta 4), tried to force Yosemite to point to Ruby 1.8 instead of 2.0, and later realized (August 31, 2014) that I didn't need to do anything as TextMate points automatically to 1.8.

Comment: See [TextMate list](http://lists.macromates.com/textmate/2014-June/037569.html) post on related issue.